# Bower with Bootstrap 3

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, bower

Trying out Yeoman (1.0.4). Generated an Angular app with `yo angular`; entered `No` to installing Bootstrap with Sass, as I wanted Bootstrap v 3 with LESS.

After scaffolding, to get Bootstrap 3, I entered:

`bower install bootstrap`

That installed bootstrap into `bower_components/bootstrap` folder. But it did not link/include Bootstrap's CSS or JS in `index.html` file. Why?

The `index.html` file does have Angular js files from bower_components folder:

```
    <!-- build:js scripts/modules.js -->
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

But not bootstrap files. Why? Do I have to add/link to them *manually*? What am I doing wrong? How can I add Bootstrap *after* generating a scaffold for my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must edit the index.html. Yeoman generator builds the base index.html. Bower only downloads dependencies as packages... but that's all, it doesn't know anything else about your app and how are you going to use the packages it downloaded. You must add the desired files by yourself.

Comment: You can do a `$ grunt wiredep` after installing your dependencies

Answer (score 4):

According to yeoman's **[Getting Started guide](http://yeoman.io/gettingstarted.html)**:

```
# Install it and save it to bower.json
>bower install jquery-pjax --save

# If you're not using RequireJS...
>grunt bower-install
```

This is supposed to inject your dependencies into your `index.html` file.

---

<sub>**Note**:

There is some setting up that needs to be done, before being able to use `bower-install`.

See, **[here](http://stephenplusplus.github.io/grunt-bower-install/)** for more details.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

With https://github.com/stephenplusplus/grunt-bower-install, if you have the following in your index.html

```
<!-- build:js scripts/vendor.js -->
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/sass-bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Then bower install will add the vendor files to your html whenever it runs. Otherwise, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Using yeoman, you install dependencies with the `--save` flag to update the bower.json file.

After that, you run `$ bower update`(optional) and do a `$ grunt wiredep`to inject the dependencies into your `index.html`.

If you look at the comments in your `index.html` generated by Yeoman, you will see something like:

```
    <!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <script src="bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/json3/lib/json3.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-block-ui/dist/angular-block-ui.js"></script>
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->
```

It is within those comments that the dependencies will be injected

Answer (score 0):

Wiredep does it without depending on Grunt or any other build tool: https://github.com/taptapship/wiredep

`npm install --save wiredep`

Insert placeholders in your code where your dependencies will be injected:

```
<html>
<head>
  <!-- bower:css -->
  <!-- endbower -->
</head>
<body>
  <!-- bower:js -->
  <!-- endbower -->
</body>
</html>
```

Let wiredep work its magic:

```
$ node
> require('wiredep')({ src: 'index.html' });
```

Since Bootstrap version 3.3.5, the bootstrap.css file has been removed from Bootstrap's package manager json. Thus, I had to roll back to version `3.3.4` before running `wiredep`.

```
bower install --save bootstrap#3.3.4
```